# What is the source of the Navadurga Stotram and Stuti?

Tags: identification-request, shaktism, chakras, nava-durga

The Navadurga stotram comprises of nine/ten verses, with each verse describing one aspect of the nine-formed goddess.

Quoting from the document hosted by [Sanskritdocuments](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/navadurga.html)

> ### नवदुर्गास्तोत्रम्
>
> **। देवी शैलपुत्री ।**
>
> ```
>  वन्दे वाञ्छितलाभाय चन्द्रार्धकृतशेखराम् ।
>  वृषारूढां शूलधरां शैलपुत्रीं यशस्विनीम् ॥
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **। देवी ब्रह्मचारिणी ।**
>
> ```
>  दधाना करपद्माभ्यामक्षमालाकमण्डलू ।
>  देवी प्रसीदतु मयि ब्रह्मचारिण्यनुत्तमा ॥
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **। देवी चन्द्रघण्टेति ।**
>
> ```
>  पिण्डजप्रवरारूढा चण्डकोपास्त्रकैर्युता ।
>  प्रसादं तनुते मह्यं चन्द्रघण्टेति विश्रुता ॥
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **। देवी कूष्मांडा ।**
>
> ```
>  सुरासम्पूर्णकलशं रुधिराप्लुतमेव च ।
>  दधाना हस्तपद्माभ्यां कूष्माण्डा शुभदास्तु मे ॥
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **। देवीस्कन्दमाता ।**
>
> ```
>  सिंहासनगता नित्यं पद्माश्रितकरद्वया ।
>  शुभदास्तु सदा देवी स्कन्दमाता यशस्विनी ॥
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **। देवीकात्यायनी ।**
>
> ```
>  चन्द्रहासोज्ज्वलकरा शार्दूलवरवाहना ।
>  कात्यायनी शुभं दद्यादेवी दानवघातिनी ॥
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **। देवीकालरात्रि ।**
>
> ```
>  एकवेणी जपाकर्णपूरा नग्ना खरास्थिता ।
>  लम्बोष्ठी कर्णिकाकर्णी तैलाभ्यक्तशरीरिणी ॥
>
>  वामपादोल्लसल्लोहलताकण्टकभूषणा ।  
>  वर्धन्मूर्धध्वजा कृष्णा कालरात्रिर्भयङ्करी ॥
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **। देवीमहागौरी ।**
>
> ```
>  श्वेते वृषे समारूढा श्वेताम्बरधरा शुचिः ।
>  महागौरी शुभं दद्यान्महादेवप्रमोददा ॥
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **। देवीसिद्धिदात्रि ।**
>
> ```
>  सिद्धगन्धर्वयक्षाद्यैरसुरैरमरैरपि ।
>  सेव्यमाना सदा भूयात् सिद्धिदा सिद्धिदायिनी ॥
> ```
>
> इति नवदुर्गास्तोत्रं सम्पूर्णम् ।

Further,

As per this document hosted again by the [Sanskritdocuments](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/navadurgAstutikuNDalinI.html), the full version of the above stotram is cited, named - 'Nava-Durga Stuti', which makes a correlation between the nine durgas and nine bodily chakras, starting from 'Muladhara' with Shailaputri, and ending at 'Nirvana-Chakra' with Siddhidatri.

However, we observe that Uptil, Ajña Chakra with Katyayanin the six popular chakras are given,

But the Kaalratri, Mahagauri & Siddhidatri are told to preside over 'Bhanu Chakra (भानु-चक्र),' Soma Chakra (सोम-चक्र), and the 'Nirvana Chakra (निर्वाण-चक्र) respectively.

So, questions -

1. **What is the source text of this' nava-durga stotram' and 'navadurga-stuti' composition(s)?**
2. **What are 'Bhanu Chakra (भानु-चक्र)', 'Soma Chakra (सोम-चक्र)', and the 'Nirvana Chakra (निर्वाण-चक्र)'?**